# Securing the rest endpoint exposed to twilio for incoming message

Tags: rest, twilio, microservices

In my application, I am exposing a rest endpoint and configured it in twilio account for the incoming message.
Now since the request is not coming from a logged in user but from an external customer, there is no token sent in the request and so the exposed API is not secure.

Is there a way I can make it secure apart from making it a https call?

Answer (score 0):

That is what `x-twilio-signature` should be used for. The Webhook requests from Twilio will have this HTTP Request Header. You can read more in implementation, below.

[How to secure Twilio webhook URLs in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-secure-twilio-webhook-urls-in-nodejs)

[Security](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security)

Answer (score 0):

Asides for what @Alan mentioned , I would also make your URL hard to guess.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/325806/are-private-unguessable-urls-equivalent-to-password-based-authentication